# set minimum variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm working on making a lightbox photo gallery. I want a counter that says eg.: photo 1 from 3.

```
var imagenumber = 0;
var imagenumber_count = 1;

function prev_btn() {

    if (imagenumber_count < 1) {
        imagenumber_count = 1;
        document.getElementById('counter_txt').innerHTML = imagenumber_count;
    } else {
        imagenumber_count -= 1;
        document.getElementById('counter_txt').innerHTML = imagenumber_count;
    }
```

When I clicked a few times on the prev. button and than I clicked on the next button `imagenumber_count+=1;`, I got a number in the negative e.g.: `-1`

Is there anyone who can help me, please?

EDIT: function of the next btn: `function next_btn(){imagenumber_count+=1;}'`

Comment: Where is the rest of your code, containing `imagenumber_count+=1;` and what is actually the problem? What should it be instead of `-1`?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the missing code...

Comment: 'function next_btn(){imagenumber_count+=1;}' it is the function of the next button. -1 is a negative number. When the number is 1, the minimum, and I clicked a few times on the prev btn, the value of the variable goes in a negative number like -1 or -2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would be more simple

```
function prev_btn() {

  if (imagenumber_count > 1) {
    imagenumber_count -= 1;
    document.getElementById('counter_txt').innerHTML = imagenumber_count;
  }
}
```

Comment: *"we wrote the same code at the same time.. what are the chances... hehehe"* Nonsense, I wrote mine a whole 52 seconds earlier! Eons! ;-)

Comment: agree :D i stopped to light a cigarette before clicking the button

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify that a fair bit:

```
function prev_btn() {

    if (imagenumber_count > 1) {
        imagenumber_count -= 1;
        document.getElementById('counter_txt').innerHTML = imagenumber_count;
    }
}
```

That assumes you didn't have *other* code that decrements `imagenumber_count`, and it assumes you don't want `imagenumber_count` to ever be `0`. If `0` is a valid value for it, change the `> 1` to `> 0`.

Comment: T.J. we wrote the same code at the same time.. what are the chances... hehehe

Answer (score 0):

Use this `if` statement instead:

```
if(imagenumber_count > 1) {
    imagenumber_count -= 1;
    document.getElementById('counter_txt').innerHTML = imagenumber_count;
}
```